# Is there any way to use Linux integrated security for MongoDb?

Tags: security, mongodb

We have c# web app connecting MongoDb deployed on Linux server. The idea is to use single designated Linux account for our web application to login and connect into MongoDb. As I understand from what I read, MongoDb does not support integrated security at all by default, it supposed to have its own user database with passwords, and no roles too, right? If so, I wonder if there is any separate third-party framework/tool or something that helps me use desired approach?

Other than that, if you know good online article regarding best practices to implement Security for Mongo in web applications, like where and how to store users and encrypted passwords etc., please give me a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please give me a link.

I did some security documentation a few months ago for MongoDB and it can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security), this should be your starting point.

- As I understand from what I read, MongoDb does not support integrated security at all by default, it supposed to have its own user database with passwords, and no roles too, right?

Up until MongoDB 2.2, authentication and authorisation is all local.In 2.2, there is limited RBAC (Role Based Access), i.e. two roles "read" and "write", with "write" being able to do everything on that database, i.e. admin.

Things will change in 2.4 with new roles:

```
name            description of privilege

read            ability to query data in any collection in the database, other than 'system.users', and also ability to run any command without an A or W attribute

readWrite       everything permitted by 'read' privilege, and also the ability to insert, update,
or remove documents or indexes in any collection other than 'system.users', and also the ability to run any command without an A attribute

userAdmin       ability to read and write the 'system.users' collection

dbAdmin         ability to run admin commands affecting a single database; see list below

serverAdmin     ability to run admin commands affecting the entire database server; Can only be set on admin database; see discussion

clusterAdmin    admin commands for a cluster of shards or a replica set; Can only be set on admin database
```

as documented [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3198). This enhanced RBAC  will be available in all versions of MongoDB from 2.3.2 (development build) and the next production release, 2.4.0.

With MongoDB 2.4, there will also be the ability to use Kerberos for authentication, however, this delegated authentication will only be available in the Enterprise builds, which require a Commercial Support contract for us.

There is currently nothing within MongoDB that enforces password complexity but obviously in 2.4 with Kerberos, the KDC can do this. You will manually have to ensure (through your internal password policy etc) that users realise the issues of using non-complex passwords and re-using the same passwords on multiple devices. Assuming you are running 2.2, all logins, passwords and permissions for MongoDB access are stored in the system.users collection under each database. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-authentication/) is the exact link to the documentation that you should read.

Comment: Is Mongo 2.4 Release planned on Jan 31, 2013? That is when I can start using all this new features, right? Thanks

Comment: @YMC: The exact 2.4 release date depends on final testing & QA acceptance, but you can track the progress via [MongoDB Jira SERVER roadmap](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aroadmap-panel) and release announcements in the [mongodb-announce google group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-announce).  The 2.3.2 development/unstable release should be out soon for testing, or you can download a [nightly build](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) if you're really keen to preview/test the new security features.